# tinymce not compatible with jquery ajaxsetup datafilter

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I use the following datafilter option on my jquery ajaxsetup:

```
    dataFilter: function(data)
    {
        var msg;
        if (typeof (JSON) !== 'undefined' &&
        typeof (JSON.parse) === 'function' &&
        data != undefined &&
        data != null &&
        data.length != 0 &&
        data != " ")
            msg = JSON.parse(data);
        else
            msg = eval('(' + data + ')');
        if (msg.hasOwnProperty('d'))
            return msg.d;
        else
            return msg;
    },
```

When I put this in the  `$.ajaxSetup({,` tinymce does not initialize on my textarea (just shows the original textarea as if tinymce is not installed).  If I move that filter to the actual ajax calls, I have no problem and everything is fine.  Note I am doing my saves myself to an ajax enabled .asmx file and it works fine.

jquery 1.4.3, tinymce jquery version 3.3.9.2

Why would the ajaxsetup option for the datafilter cause tinymce to not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't tell why exactly TinyMCE fails but you could make a function to filter only your own requests and let TinyMCE be.

```
function filAjax( settings ) {
  $.ajax(
    $.extend(settings, 
    {
       dataFilter: function(data) {
         var msg;
         if (typeof (JSON) !== 'undefined' &&
         typeof (JSON.parse) === 'function' &&
         data != undefined &&
         data != null &&
         data.length != 0 &&
         data != " ")
             msg = JSON.parse(data);
         else
             msg = eval('(' + data + ')');
         if (msg.hasOwnProperty('d'))
             return msg.d;
         else
             return msg;
         }
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much the same as what I did when I simply moved it from the ajaxsetup to the ajax call itself.